# MySQL запрос на поиск отрицательного значения

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, запрос

не могу нормально сформировать запрос для планировщика событий в phpmyadmin.
Есть бд "main", в ней таблица "withdraws", в этой таблице интересует значение поля "amount".

---

Собственно сама задача, найти запись в таблице withdraws, в которой amount будет отрицательным, например -1, -100 ... В случае, если такая запись находится - удалить её.

Comment: Сам запрос `delete from table where amount<0`, но вы же что то другое хотели спросить ?

Comment: Моя цель, это засунуть запрос в планировщик событий, чтобы он каждые 1-2 минуты проверял таблицу на наличие записей с отрицательной суммой, т.к. это приводит к множеству ошибок

Comment: Возможно для этого корректнее использовать триггеры в phpmyadmin, но я очень слаб в работе с бд, нужно почитать об этом. Но проблему нужно было решить быстро, спасибо за помощь, ваш запрос сработал как нужно!